# Why won't my Excel 2010 spreadsheet appear in my Word 2010 document?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010

When I try to embed an Excel spreadsheeet in a Word document by clicking Insert → Table, "Excel Spreadsheet", a spreadsheet does not appear. Instead `{ EMBED Excel.Sheet.12 }` appears and Excel opens.

How do I fix this? I have had it appear in the document before and I was able to work on the spreadsheet right there and when I was done I could just click outside of spreadsheet but on the Word document and my spreasheet would be part of the document. It was really easy. I must have clicked on something along way.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle Field Codes, that'll fix it.